# Can the recv() function receive more bytes than its internal buffer?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, recv, getsockopt

I am new to sockets in Linux and trying to understand how the `recv()` works. Tried a scenario where I couldn't find an explanation clearly. I hope somebody out there can enlighten me. Here is the scenario:

Using TCP Sockets to send data of 5 MiB between two process (Sender and Receiver). I execute these process on i.MX6 Sabrelite board which is running Linux.

Sender.cpp:

```
char buffer[5MB];
send(sendSocket, (void*) buffer, 5 MiB, 0);
```

Receiver.cpp:

```
char buffer[5 MiB];
int count = 0;
do {
    rbytes = recv(receiveSocket, (void*) buffer, 5MB, 0);
    printf("Recv'd %d. %d\n",count,rbytes);
    count++;
} while (rbytes!=0);
```

I used the `getsockopt()` function call before receiving to get the internal buffer `SO_RCVBUF` size. It was around 86 KiB.

I wanted to see how many `recv()` calls did it take to get 5 MiB and how many bytes for each `recv()` call.

After receiving 5 MiB I check the output. It nearly takes 48 `recv()` calls to get 5 MiB of data. For the first 40 calls it received less than 86 KiB which makes sense as bytes received is less than the internal buffer. If I had received double of 86 KiB then some explanation I had come across was that the kernel usually allocates twice of what is shown in `SO_RCVBUF`.

But I am receiving more bytes than the double of 86 KiB.

Can I trust the `SO_RCVBUF` size using `getsockopt()`?

Does it dynamically change its values?

Just tried another iteration of the same scenario. The number of `recv()` call varies. But the bytes I receive is sometimes more than allocated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1207.2/01561.html), the kernel allocates twice as much buffer space as you request with SO_RCVBUF.

Comment: I saw a similar explanation in another thread. But what I see is I recv more than the twice of the allocated buffer

Comment: `SO_RCVBUF` is only a hint, the actual memory allocated depends on the network stats, use `ss -tm` to check it